# to find maximum point from the graph/plot

Tags: matlab

a= [1 2 13 20 10 20 12 1 13 14]

b= [1:10:100]

plot(a,b)
I want to find the maximum('a') from the plot and then take the corresponding point let say 'a3,b3' and store it some where else and remove it from the plot. then I want to subtract 'a3' from every point left in 'a' and plot the graph. and I need to do this again till it reaches an thresh hold point.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When you ask for help, you should not only describe your problem clearly (which you did), but also show what you've already tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an odd request but if I understand correctly.

```
%Input data
a = [1 2 13 20 10 20 12 1 13 14];
b = [1:10:100];

%Some threshold (which you didn't specify
lengthA = 4;

%Initialize storage vector
aPrime = a;
bPrime = b;

%While vector
while (length(aPrime) >= lengthA)
    %New figure
    figure;

    %Plot vector
    plot(aPrime, bPrime)

    %Find index and max value in a'
    [aMax, index] = max(aPrime);

    %Find max value in b'
    bMax = bPrime(index);

    %Remove max value from vector and subtract off max value
    aPrime = aPrime([1:index - 1, index + 1:end]) - aMax;
    bPrime = bPrime([1:index - 1, index + 1:end]) - bMax;
end
```